# "Write error (disk full?)" when trying to unpack NOOBS on to an SD card

Tags: sd-card

The raspbian fails to load. Tried to unpack NOOBS archive file but received error insufficient space

```
sudo unzip noobs282.zip
...
inflating: os/Raspbian/root.tar.xz  
os/Raspbian/root.tar.xz:  write error (disk full?).  Continue? (y/n/^C)

lsblk
lsblk: dm-0: failed to get device path
lsblk: dm-0: failed to get device path
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                   8:0    1 14.8G  1 disk 
├─sda1                8:1    1  1.2G  1 part /var/host/media/removable/RECOVERY
├─sda5                8:5    1   32M  1 part /var/host/media/removable/SETTINGS
├─sda6                8:6    1   66M  1 part /var/host/media/removable/boot
├─sda7                8:7    1    6G  1 part 
├─sda8                8:8    1   80M  1 part /var/host/media/removable/boot-rbp2
├─sda9                8:9    1  3.7G  1 part /var/host/media/removable/root-rbp2
├─sda10               8:10   1   60M  1 part /var/host/media/removable/boot0
├─sda11               8:11   1    2G  1 part /var/host/media/removable/root0
└─sda12               8:12   1  1.7G  1 part /var/host/media/removable/share
loop0                 7:0    0  3.1G  0 loop 
└─encstateful       253:1    0  3.1G  0 dm   /var/host/timezone
loop1                 7:1    0 14.8M  1 loop 
└─b9...
                    253:2    0 14.6M  1 dm   
zram0               252:0    0  2.8G  0 disk [SWAP]
mmcblk0rpmb         179:48   0    4M  0 disk 
mmcblk0boot0        179:16   0    4M  1 disk 
mmcblk0boot1        179:32   0    4M  1 disk 
mmcblk0             179:0    0 14.7G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1         179:1    0 10.5G  0 part /
├─mmcblk0p2         179:2    0   16M  0 part 
├─mmcblk0p3         179:3    0    2G  0 part 
├─mmcblk0p4         179:4    0   16M  0 part 
├─mmcblk0p5         179:5    0    2G  0 part 
├─mmcblk0p6         179:6       512B  0 part 
├─mmcblk0p7         179:7       512B  0 part 
├─mmcblk0p8         179:8        16M  0 part 
├─mmcblk0p9         179:9       512B  0 part 
├─mmcblk0p10        179:10      512B  0 part 
├─mmcblk0p11        179:11        8M  0 part 
└─mmcblk0p12        179:12       16M  0 part
```

How to delete the SD card to be completely blank, then start again?

```
ls
bcm2708-rpi-0-w.dtb       bootcode.bin             recovery.elf
bcm2708-rpi-b.dtb         boot-rbp2                RECOVERY_FILES_DO_NOT_EDIT
bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb    BUILD-DATA               recovery.img
bcm2708-rpi-cm.dtb        defaults                 recovery.rfs
bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb       INSTRUCTIONS-README.txt  riscos-boot.bin
bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb       os                       root0
bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb  overlays                 root-rbp2
bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb       RECOVERY                 SD Card
boot                      recovery7.img            SETTINGS
boot0                     recovery.cmdline         share

sudo rm -drf boot
rm: cannot remove ‘boot/overlays/adau7002-simple.dtbo’: Read-only file system
```

Changed position of lock key on side of SD card holder, same read-only error.

Please, how to start with a new SD card?

Answer (score 1):

If you want Raspbian don’t bother with Noobs.

1 Download Raspbian Stretch with Desktop (no need to unzip) https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

2 Flash to sd card with Etcher https://etcher.io

3 Place sd card in Pi and boot

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Followed the instructions on the github page (https://github.com/resin-io/etcher).
Even though the lock switch is up (towards the terminals connectors), the raspberry pi sd card holder is "locked" according to the etcher dialogue window.
Any advice?

Comment: Try another sd card.

Comment: yep, sounds like the SD card is toast